# One-to-Many composition and data retrieval

Tags: oop, rdbms

This is a classic problem that I could never seem to come up with a solution for that I was happy with.  What would be considered an OO-elegant and DB-scalable approach to this problem?

```
Employee
- Name, Phone, Meta, etc

Company
- Meta, etc
- Employee[]

CompanyRepository (RDMBS)
- Company GetById(int)
- Company[] GetAll()
```

**Approach #1:**
'GetById' Selects all from 'tCompany' and left joins 'tEmployee'.  Sql Select yields 12 rows.  Returns a single company populated with 12 employees.

'GetAll' Same Select as above but returns 12,000,000 rows.  Through creative loops and logic returns 1,000,000 companies each with 12 employees.

**Approach #2:**
'GetById' ... same as above

'GetAll'.  Selects all from 'tCompany' but nothing from 'tEmployee'.  Sql select yields 1,000,000 rows.  Returns 1,000,000 companies but each with a null 'Employees' property.

**Approach #3**
... split the domain into 'SimpleCompany' containing only meta and 'ComplexCompany' that inherits from 'SimpleCompany' but has a 'Employees' property.  GetById returns 'ComplexCompany' and GetAll returns 'SimpleCompany' array.

... each smells bad for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What is business reason to get all companies (12,000,000 rows)? I would not advise you to have all 12,000,000 rows in memory at a time.

May be you should use pagination. Select limited set of companies at a time, then iterate from one page to another until no rows are returned.

```
public Company[] GetAllByPageNumber(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
```

The down side here is that Company should not be inserted or deleted while  you are iterating.